# Ace Editor auto completion, less priority for local snippets / text

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, editor, ace-editor

I am using the Ace Editor for a project and i have a little problem.

I add with the function addCompleter some keywords, macros and stuff to the editor. But the local completer seems to override all of them, once they are written. Like in this example, the first time you type there is "MOM_Abort" with the meta tag "NOT LOCAL". The second time it is already a "local".

Why is that so important for me: In the real project i show up the documentation about the Keywords next to them, but they disappear when Ace Editor overrides them with local variables. I tried out some things but nothing i found was effective.

I want the local variables have less priority, because i don't want to delete them all over, is that possible?

Here is my Ace Editor Code:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/9eh00xtc/1/
```

```js
var editor = ace.edit("editor");
editor.setTheme("ace/theme/monokai");
var langTools = ace.require("ace/ext/language_tools");

editor.setOptions({
  enableBasicAutocompletion: true,
  enableLiveAutocompletion: true,
  enableSnippets: true,
});

var completer = {
  getCompletions: function(editor, session, pos, prefix, callback) {
    var completions = [];
    completions.push({
      caption: "MOM_Abort",
      snippet: "MOM_Abort",
      meta: "NOT LOCAL"
    });
    callback(null, completions);
  }
}
langTools.addCompleter(completer);
```

```css
#editor {
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://rawgit.com/ajaxorg/ace-builds/master/src-noconflict/ace.js"></script>
<script src="http://rawgit.com/ajaxorg/ace-builds/master/src-noconflict/ext-language_tools.js"></script>

<pre id="editor" style="font-family: courier;"></pre>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The completions are sorted by their score (see: [issue](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/issues/2485)). So simply add a `score` field to your completions and set it to 1000. That will make them show first.